# iPhone, how can I show a small nib modally so it doesn't occupy the whole screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to show a small dialog on top of my existing views (so then can be seen). I've adjusted the size of my SmallTutorialDialog but when I load it it occupies the whole screen.

How can I adjust this ?

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewDidAppear:animated];

SmallTutorialDialog *lvc = [[SmallTutorialDialog alloc] 
  initWithNibName:@"SmallTutorialDialog" bundle:nil];

[self presentModalViewController:lvc animated:NO];

[lvc release];

}
```

Comment: xcode tag should be used, if u ask smthg about the program xcode itself — not about code u wrote with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, you can't. According to the iOS Class Reference:

> Resizes its view and attaches it to
>   the view hierarchy.

Workaround:

Create a view that houses your small view controller and animate it (see CABasicAnimation) to obtain the desired effect.

Comment: Programmatically create a UIView with the size of your small view controller. Add your small view controller as a subview to that UIView. Add the UIView as a subview to the view you want to display it on and make sure to set its location to below the view so it is completely hidden. Either change the location to display it, or animate the location using CABasicAnimation.

Comment: You can add any view controller to a view. You may run into other problems, however. The best way is to use what Apple has provided. In your case, present the view modally on the entire screen. That way, they cannot reject it for not following the UI guidelines.

Comment: No, you can add a view controller to a view. `ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:bundle:]; [myView addSubview:vc.view];` Where `myView` is the view you would display to the user; it should be the same size as the view controller you are adding.

Comment: Any modal view controllers should always be presented using `presentModalViewController`.

Comment: Ok I can add a view using addSubView on top of a modal view, however, I need be able to lock the view underneath, any ideas ?

Comment: Create a semi-transparent view the size of the screen. Add your modal view to that view. This is similar to the "dim" effect on Windows Vista/Windows 7 User Account Control.

Comment: When I add a modal view its full screen and I can't make it transparent

Comment: The iPad supports this but the iPhone/iPod touch does not.  There are additional details in the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS" which pretty much answers your question here.  Additionally the 4.2 beta documentation has further details than are discussed here.  G'luck!